# Adding a hidden row to a table in IE8 gives unexpected spaces

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-8

This is something weird that is observed. Inside a table
there are few rows which keeps on incresing at every 5th row `'on change'` So to perform few operations there are `hidden` field
added to each row. This works perfectly fine in Firefox but
in IE8 the hidden row adds up near the starting of table and
creating a space between rows and header as shown below:

[image]

On close inspection (IE developer tools,F12) it shown the
hidden rows are the ones which are adding up the space as shown. Can anyone suggest how to maintain the hidden value without disturbing the table header space.

[image]

I tried an alternate solution by adding up as part of a `<td>` which is giving unexpected results because the rows are behave something independently works upon based on conditions and the also columns can be shown or hidden. So I definitely want it to be outside of all `<td>s` but inside a `<tr>` can somebody please help. Please also explain why there is no problem in FireFox

Comment: What happens if you style them accordingly to have a relative position and height of 0px?

Comment: @Graeme can you give a close example please

Comment: instead of making it hidden... style it.. i.e class name of "hiddenrow" .hiddenrow {display:block; overflow:hidden; height:0px;} try that

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid to have anything except a `<th>` or `<td>` inside a `<tr>`. I suggest fixing your markup first. What is the purpose of this hidden field, BTW?

Comment: just to grab the entire row values

Comment: I would suggest adding another cell (to contain the hidden element) to each row, and then set its `visibility` or `display` property to `none`. Otherwise, 'hidden' fields obviously do not show up in the form, so you can really put it in any cell in the row...